# JQuery attr() on div not returning value

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, attr

I'm working with a Backbone app written in Coffeescript. I'm trying to access the cid associated with each div in a list of divs. Each div has the same 'contact' class and cid with an associated integer value.

```
<div class="contact-list">
  <div class="contact" cid="1"></div>
  <div class="contact" cid="2"></div>
  <div class="contact" cid="3"></div>
  <div class="contact" cid="4"></div>
  <div class="contact" cid="5"></div>
</div>
```

I want to find the element with a cid of 4:

```
console.log "ALL", $('.contact')

for div in $('.contact') 
  console.log div
  console.log div.attr('cid')
```

The loop appears to break upon calling .attr(). (When I comment out the line, the code prints all 5 divs. Otherwise it prints only the first) This suggests I must be calling .attr() incorrectly?

Comment: did you try `$(div).attr("cid")`?

Comment: Surely you get some error message in the console?

Comment: @Juhana, nope, it just breaks it. That's it, @Jordumus! I knew I was missing jQuery somehow. Post it as an answer!

Comment: others have posted it as answer already ;) feel free to give them the credit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When iterating over a jQuery object the element reference will be referring to the DOM element not a jQuery object so you can't access jQuery methods directly on it

```
console.log "ALL", $('.contact')

for div in $('.contact') 
  console.log $(div)
  console.log $(div).attr('cid')
```

---

Use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each) like

```
console.log "ALL", $('.contact')

$('.contact').each (i, div) ->
  console.log div
  console.log $(div).attr('cid')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n3zv7ksh/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the div through sizzle again as attr doesn't work on non jquery objects. $(div).attr(). Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use data ... [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

U can put value

```
$div.data("cid", "test" );
```

and u can read value

```
$div.data("cid")
```